# Odd Laravel apiResource routes issue

Tags: api, laravel-5, routes

the route for my show function in an apiResource is not working, but if I overload the route and point to the function it works as expected.

resource route does note work

```
Route::apiResource('/delivery_handler/chat/','CartDeliveryListChatController');
```

working route

```
Route::get('/delivery_handler/chat/{id?}', function ($id) {
        return (new App\Http\Controllers\Api\CartDeliveryListChatController)->show($id);
    });
```

in my controller

```
    /**
     * @param $chatId
     * @return CartDeliveryListChatResource
     */
    public function show($chatId): CartDeliveryListChatResource
    {
        $data = CartDeliveryListChat::where('id',$chatId)->first();
        return new CartDeliveryListChatResource($data);
    }
```

the routes list

```
  | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/delivery_handler/chat/{id?}                  |                                   | Closure                                                                             | api          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/delivery_handler/chat/{}                     | show                              | App\Http\Controllers\Api\CartDeliveryListChatController@show                        | api          |
```

Comment: I think this is a namespace issue, what happens when you specify the namespace in your first code example? Do you see any errors at all. can you specify what exactly you see not working

Answer (score 0):

Okay i think the problem is the namespacing. I think you are missing the API part in the resource route definition. Your controller is in the `App\Http\Controllers\Api` directory, but if you just define `CartDeliveryListChatController` Laravel will only look in the `App\Http\Controllers` directory.

Try the following:

```
Route::apiResource('/delivery_handler/chat/','Api\CartDeliveryListChatController');
```

Also i dont know if you can specify a path in as the first parameter of the resource method. I thought that always had to be an entity name (which you create the resource for). But i am not sure about that. If it still does not work, try this instead:

```
Route::apiResource('cartdeliverylistchat','Api\CartDeliveryListChatController');
```

And route `http://YOURAPPLICATION/cartdeliverylistchat/YOURID`

Comment: hmmm tried this, but still does not return.  what is odd is that all the other routes besides show work as intended... so index, update, destroy etc. 


This is a problem with about 1/2 of my controllers, though some work correctly though they are all following the same pattern.   

As a side note adding the path works (as long as it does not get confused with a different route. )

Comment: also I guess I should add all these routes are already in a group namespaced with the Api, which is why I did not need to directly assign the api to the controller.  ```
```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api','prefix'=>'v1'], function () {
   Routes are here
}
```